# How to make unclickable column in clickable row

Tags: jquery, html, tablerow, clickable

I use clickable rows in my table:

```
<tbody>
   <tr class="clickable-row data-href='url://'>
        <th>First</th>
        <th>Second</th>
        <th>Third</th>
   </tr>
</tbody>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
            window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
        });
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
    });
</script>
```

How to make column First unclickable?

Comment: <tr class="clickable-row" data-href="url://"> change second row with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$(".clickable-row").click(function() {
```

To listen specifically to the columns, i.e. `td`, instead:

```
$(".clickable-row").on('click', 'td', function() {
    if (!$(this).index()) return;
```

`!$(this).index()` is a short way of saying, "if the index of the clicked column is 0", i.e. the first column.

Comment: Glad to be of help. If one of us solved your problem please upvote and/or accept the answer.